# Example of infinite game without any Nash equiblibria

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

I have to find an example of a game that does not admit (mixed strategy) Nash equilibria.

Consider a game in normal form. Let $N=\{1,2\}$ be set of players and $S_i=\mathbb{R}$ a set of possible strategies for each player (uncountably many), $i=1,2$.

The rules of this game are as follows: each player chooses one real number (his strategy). Player who chose a bigger number than the other player wins $1$, player who chose smaller number gets $0$. If both players choose the same number, they both get $0$.

Formally, payoff functions of each player one looks like this:
$$v_1(s_1,s_2)=\left\{\begin{matrix} 1 \ \mathrm{if}\ s_1>s_2 \\ 0 \ \mathrm{if}\ s_1\leq s_2 \end{matrix}\right. $$
$$v_2(s_1,s_2)=\left\{\begin{matrix} 1 \ \mathrm{if}\ s_2>s_1 \\ 0 \ \mathrm{if}\ s_2\leq s_1 \end{matrix}\right. $$

Do you think it's a good example?

Comment: It looks ok, but – just my two cents – I would choose $(0,1)$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$ to emphasize that the set of strategies of a player can indeed be uncountably infinite, but it has to be compact.

Comment: But $(0,1)$ is not compact as far as I know...

Comment: Indeed, that's the point. If you choose $[0,1]$ (that is compact), you have uncountably many strategies for every player and a NE (think about Cournot's duopoly).

Comment: In my game also - if set of strategies was $[0,1]$, then $(1,1)$ would be pure strategy Nash equilibrium. Ok, thanks.

Comment: You just wrote the example. You did not **prove** that it has no mixed strategy Nash equilibrium.

Answer (score -3):

There is none, unless the problem is wrongly planned. By definition, every game has at least one equilibrium in mixed strategies.

Comment: Please post this as a comment.

Comment: This is absolutely WRONG !! By application of Kakutani's fixed point theorem, if the players have infinite strategies and this set is not compact, then there is no guarantee that there will be a NE in the game.